# Regex to remove the uri prefix (within tag) only from xml tag

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to remove the uri prefix(within tag) only from xml tag.

**Example**

input:

```
<ns1:fso xlmns:="http://xyz"><sender>abc</sender></ns1:fso>
```

output:

```
<fso xlmns:="http://xyz"><sender>abc</sender></fso>
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class RegularExpressionTest {

    private static String REGEX1 = "<\\/?([a-z0-9]+?:).*?>";

    private static String INPUT = "<ns1:fso xmlns:ns1='https://www.example.com/fsoCanonical'>
 <ns2:senderId xmlns='http://www.example.com/fsoCanonical'>abc</ns2:senderId>
 <receiverId xmlns='http://www.example.com/fsoCanonical'>testdata</receiverId>   
  <messageId xmlns='http://www.example.com/fsoCanonical'>4CF4DC05126A0077E10080000A66C871</messageId>    
</ns1:fso> ";

  private static String REPLACE = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX1);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT); // get a matcher object
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, REPLACE);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
```

I am not able to paste the input XML here

> `private static String INPUT =`

is not the correct one as shown in above code. Instead you can take any example of soap message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more used with PERLs RegEx engine, but if it works the same, this could be it:

```
private static String REGEX1 = "(<\\/?)[a-z0-9]+:";
```

and

```
private static String REPLACE = "$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match `ns1` with following regex:

```
<\/?([a-z0-9]+?:).*?>
```

Comment: It matches well `ns1:` - so you just have to replace it to an empty string.

Comment: Post your code that you got already to do that (edit your question - not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

I would improve this code. I should not remove the soapenv,body and header...

(</?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:(?!Header|Body|Envelope)

I would include de A-Z as well....